# How to separate values dots of stripplot for my two sub categories violin plots?

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

I have two sub categories 'Stage 10' and 'Stage 13' under the main category 'Control'.

I want to show the value dots with `stripplot`. The problem is that the value dots now are at the middle between the two violins. But I want the dots to be on each violin. How can I do it?

My current violin plot looks like the attached image.

[image]

My code is:

```
sns.violinplot(data=transposed_df, x="Genotype", y="Normalized_PGC", hue="Stage", inner=None)
sns.stripplot(data=transposed_df, x="Genotype", y="Normalized_PGC", jitter=True, color='black', size=5)
```

Comment: Did you try setting `dodge=True` in the stripplot?

Comment: You also need `hue=` in stripplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent observations as points inside the distribution by setting `inner="point"` in the arguments, then you don't even need to add a stripplot:

```py
sns.violinplot(data=transposed_df, x="Genotype", y="Normalized_PGC", hue="Stage", inner="point")
```

With simple synthetic data it should look like this

```py
x = np.random.normal(0,2,100)
y = ['A' if val < 0 else 'B' for val in x]

df = pd.DataFrame({'val' : x, 'label' : y})
sns.violinplot(data=df, x="label", y="val", inner="point")
```

**Output:**

[image]